# highcharts sparklines how to scale x-axis in each row to the same

Tags: jquery, highcharts, sparklines

i am using highchart sparklines in my table. This is my code to generate the sparklines. It is generated using a php script. So you will find some php variables inside:

```
$(function () {
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        Highcharts.SparkLine = function (a, b, c) {
                            const hasRenderToArg = typeof a === 'string' || a.nodeName;
                            let options = arguments[hasRenderToArg ? 1 : 0];
                            const defaultOptions = {
                                chart: {
                                    renderTo: (options.chart && options.chart.renderTo) || (hasRenderToArg && a),
                                    backgroundColor: null,
                                    borderWidth: 0,
                                    type: 'area',
                                    margin: [2, 0, 2, 0],
                                    width: 40,
                                    height: 20,
                                    style: {
                                        overflow: 'visible'
                                    },
                                    // small optimalization, saves 1-2 ms each sparkline
                                    skipClone: true
                                },
                                title: {
                                    text: ''
                                },
                                credits: {
                                    enabled: false
                                },
                                xAxis: {
                                    labels: {
                                        enabled: false
                                    },
                                    title: {
                                        text: null
                                    },
                                    startOnTick: false,
                                    endOnTick: false,
                                    tickPositions: []
                                },
                                yAxis: {
                                    endOnTick: false,
                                    startOnTick: false,
                                    labels: {
                                        enabled: false
                                    },
                                    title: {
                                        text: null
                                    },
                                    tickPositions: [0]
                                },
                                legend: {
                                    enabled: false
                                },
                                tooltip: {
                                    hideDelay: 0,
                                    outside: true,
                                    shared: true
                                },
                                exporting: {
                                    enabled: false
                                },
                                plotOptions: {
                                    series: {
                                        animation: false,
                                        lineWidth: 2,
                                        shadow: false,
                                        states: {
                                            hover: {
                                                lineWidth: 1
                                            }
                                        },
                                        marker: {
                                            radius: 1,
                                            states: {
                                                hover: {
                                                    radius: 2
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        fillOpacity: 0.25
                                    },
                                    column: {
                                        negativeColor: '#c3d3a4',
                                        color: '#729d34',
                                        borderColor: 'none'
                                    },
                                    bar: {
                                        negativeColor: '#c3d3a4',
                                        color: '#729d34',
                                        borderColor: 'none'
                                    }
                                }
                            };
                                            
                            options = Highcharts.merge(defaultOptions, options);
                                            
                            return hasRenderToArg ?
                                new Highcharts.Chart(a, options, c) :
                                new Highcharts.Chart(options, b);
                        };
                                            
                        const start = +new Date(),
                            tds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('td[data-sparkline]')),
                            fullLen = tds.length;
                                            
                        let n = 0;
                                            
                        function doChunk() {
                            const time = +new Date(),
                                len = tds.length;
                                            
                            for (let i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
                                const td = tds[i];
                                const stringdata = td.dataset.sparkline;
                                const arr = stringdata.split('; ');
                                const data = arr[0].split(', ').map(parseFloat);
                                const chart = {};
                                            
                                if (arr[1]) {
                                    chart.type = arr[1];
                                }
                                            
                                Highcharts.SparkLine(td, {
                                    series: [{
                                        data: data,
                                        pointStart: 1
                                    }],
                                    tooltip: {
                                        headerFormat: '<span style=\"font-size: 10px\">' + td.parentElement.querySelector('th').innerText + ':</span><br/>',
                                        pointFormat: '<b>{point.y}</b>'
                                    },
                                    chart: chart
                                });
                                            
                                n += 1;
                                            
                                // If the process takes too much time, run a timeout to allow interaction with the browser
                                if (new Date() - time > 500) {
                                    tds.splice(0, i + 1);
                                    setTimeout(doChunk, 0);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        doChunk();
                    });
                });
```

I have to problems i can not solve:

1. I currently use td.parentElement.querySelector('th').innerText to get the text of the first column in the tooltip.

if my table looks like:

```
<table>
<tr><th>Amsterdam</th><td>43 People</td><td data-sparkline="-5"></td></tr>
<tr><th>Paris</th><td>20 People</td><td data-sparkline="2"></td></tr>
</table>
```

it works great.

But i like to change the table structure from th to td:

```
<table>
<tr><td>Amsterdam</td><td>43 People</td><td data-sparkline="-5"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Paris</td><td>20 People</td><td data-sparkline="2"></td></tr>
</table>
```

How can i get the first colum of the table row to be displayed in the tooltip "td.parentElement.querySelector('td:first????').innerText"

2. As you see in the picture the positive and negetive values in a row dont have the same starting point.
   [image]

It had to look like:

[image]

There should be a fixed x-axis in the middle, positive values go to the right, negative to the left and the middle-point is fixed over all rows and the scaling is the same in each rows. So bigger values have a longer bar, smaller values a short one.

Answer (score 0):

As to your questions:

1. Using `td.parentElement.querySelector('td').innerText` will be enough because `querySelector` returns only the first element that matches the specified selector.

**Live example:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1qLk93c2/

---

2. You need to set the same x-axis extremes for all of your charts. You can do that by setting the same `min` and `max` x-axis properties.

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.min